# Roblox Studio Value Issue

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a question to something that happened to me a few times while coding in Roblox Studio:
I have a simple example of the problem:

```
local Value = Instance.new("NumberValue")
Value.Value = 10 
while true do 
   print(Value.Value)
end
```

Until now everything has been working, but if I add or remove the Value of "Value" it still prints 10.
It's the same thing when I want to save the value in a Datastore it only takes the Value that was there when "Value" was created. Here's my code for saving player data.

```
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local money = player:WaitForChild("money")
    local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
    local MoneyStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayerMoney")
    local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
        MoneyStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, money.Value)
    end)
    if not success then
        print(errorMessage)
    end
    print("saved "..player.Name.."'s money! It is $"..money.Value)
end)
```

Comment: How are you setting the Value of the NumberValue?

Comment: In line 6 of the code in the brackets it says money.Value

Comment: Or do you mean how do i load the money?

`game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
 local moneyvalue = Instance.new("NumberValue",player)
 moneyvalue.Name = "money"
 local Datastoreservice = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
 local MoneyStore = Datastoreservice:GetDataStore("PlayerMoney")
 local success, Moneyload = pcall(function()
  return MoneyStore:GetAsync(player.UserId)
 end)
 if success then
  moneyvalue.Value = Moneyload
  wait(5)
 end`

Comment: How are you modifying moneyvalue in game? You mention that it's value never changes from the original value despite how you change it. What code is changing the player's money in game?

Comment: You can earn money by playing and Scripts are Aldingen like that: first Definition of money and then money.Value = money.Value + 10

Comment: @Keilorus, Sometimes im Using a local Script to change the value, because i am giving it by a GUI, so can i fire a remote with the Name of the Player?

Comment: Changes made in LocalScripts aren't replicated up to the Server. If you want the value to properly change, you need to do it in a serverside Script

Comment: Ok thank you   so much for Your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem but I think that you're using a LocalScript, please use a server script to make changes. If want the player, then there are parameters that can give you the player who touched, triggered, added or removed. If you're using UserInputService then you should use a RemoteEvent or RemoteFunction.